# How to change the umask?

Tags: debian

The umask controls the default file creation permissions, 0002 means files will have 664 and directories 775. Setting this (by editing the umask line at the bottom of /etc/profile in my case) means files created by one user will be writable by other users in the www-group without needing to chmod them.

I've looked that up, but I am told:

```
# The default umask is now handled by pam_umask.  
# See pam_umask(8) and /etc/login.defs.
```

And here I am blocked as I don't know pam_umask, I want to change the umask to 0002.
How to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [`man 8 pam_umask`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/pam_umask):

> EXAMPLES
>          Add the following line to /etc/pam.d/login to set the user specific umask at login:
>
> ```
>                session optional pam_umask.so umask=0022
> ```

You can change that value to 0002.

Answer (score 2):

The right place under debian is:

/etc/pam.d/common-session

session optional pam_umask.so umask = #VALUE (e.g. 0026)